# grouping required for fields not being aggregated error

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have the following query below. Problem is that I throws this error when executed:

```
column "v4.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Which doesn't make much sense, since I'm not using that field in a aggregate function. Any ideas as to why this is?

```
SELECT          c0."id", 
                c0."assigned_user_id", 
                c0."assigned_team_id", 
                c0."last_activity", 
                c0."last_message", 
                c3."unread_count", 
                c0."closed", 
                v4."name", 
                v4."avatar", 
                v4."id", 
                Count(c0."id") OVER() 
FROM            "conversations" AS c0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "apps"          AS a1 
ON              a1."id" = c0."app_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "conversation_users" AS c5 
ON              c5."conversation_id" = c0."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" AS u2 
ON              c5."user_id" = u2."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "conversation_users" AS c3 
ON              c3."conversation_id" = c0."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "visitors" AS v4 
ON              v4."id" = c0."visitor_id" 
WHERE           ( a1."id" = $1) 
AND             ( u2."id" = $2) 
AND             ( c3."user_id" = $3) 
GROUP BY        c0."id", 
ORDER BY        c0."last_activity" DESC ["ASnYW1-RgCl0I", "clt8ojxvk0000dp2fyvwq126", "clt8ojxvk0000dp2fyvwq126"]
```

Comment: It would seem you have an extra comma at the end of the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 3):

That is *exactly* why you want the column in the `group by`.  Formally speaking, you should really have *all* non-aggregated columns in the `group by`:

```
group by c0."id", c0."assigned_user_id", c0."assigned_team_id",
         c0."last_activity", c0."last_message", c0."closed",
         c3."unread_count", 
         v4."name", v4."avatar", v4."id"
```

Postgres has an extension (supported by the ANSI standard) that let's you replace primary or unique keys in the `group by` and still access other columns.  I have not used this with multiple tables, but this probably also works:

```
group by c0."id",
         c3."unread_count", 
         v4."id"
```

In addition, your select is using a window function.  Why do you have the `over` clause there?  This is an aggregation query, so that doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: Since you said  "formally speaking"... All non-aggregated columns  in the SELECT list _(that are not functionally dependent on grouped columns)_ must be in the GROUP BY.  The extension you refer to codifies this statement.  E.g. Since `c0.id` is in the GROUP BY all of the c0 columns don't need to be listed.

Comment: I see, the reason for the `over` clause is because I want to return the exact amount of records returned (before a limit clause) in the same query